# Querying using multiple tables

Tags: ms-access

Im a complete novice in MS Access so I was wondering if it's possbile to join multiple tables that all have the exact same field names - without duplicating the field names? So if say an Employee ID appears in 2 tables it should display results from both the tables?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an answer just by searching the internet; for example, first hit with "access join" on google:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/join-tables-and-queries-HA010096320.aspx

Comment: yeh my impatience is my downfall here, even though it would take longer to ask a question than google something lol